# Storing in class function with templated arity

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I want to have a class that represents a discrete function over integers. The arity of the function is a template parameter. A constructor should accept (pointers to?) functions of this arity. I would also like to be able to pass a lambda expression to the constructor. In fact, this is the main type of functions I will be passing.

Further, I want to have a method `eval()` to calculate the value of the function for provided arguments.

The question is how to pass and store the function and also how to evaluate it.

```cpp
template<int arity>
class DiscreteFun {
private:
    FuncType f; // what should FuncType be?
public:
    DiscreteFun(FuncType f): f(f) { };

    int eval(const array<int,arity>& x) const {
      // how to pass arguments so that it calculates f(x[0], x[1], ...)
    }
};
```

Comment: Can't you pass the `FuncType` as a template parameter as well?

Comment: Well, intuitively, FuncType should be defined by arity (i.e. if arity=3 then the function should take 3 integers and return integer).

Comment: I'd be tempted to rename `eval` to `operator()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `std::index_sequence` and some indirection:

```
template <std::size_t, typename T>
using always_t = T;

template <typename Seq> class DiscreteFunImpl;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
class DiscreteFunImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
private:
    std::function<int (always_t<Is, int>...)> f;
public:
    DiscreteFunImpl(std::function<int (always_t<Is, int>...)> f): f(f) {}

    int eval(const array<int, sizeof...(Is)>& x) const {
        return f(x[Is]...);
    }
};


template <std::size_t N>
using DiscreteFun = DiscreteFunImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `always_t` here?

Comment: It is a way to "transform" Is into type T. so in our case to have N ints.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a template parameter for the type of `f`, and then `eval` is just [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). Note that `std::array` is a tuple-like container.

```
template<int arity, typename FuncType>
class DiscreteFun {
private:
    FuncType f;
public:
    DiscreteFun(FuncType f): f(f) { };

    int eval(const array<int,arity>& x) const {
        return std::apply(f, x);
    }
};

template<int arity, typename FuncType>
DiscreteFun<arity, FuncType> makeDiscreteFun(FuncType&& f)
{
    return { std::forward<FuncType>(f) };
}
```

Comment: How then should I declare somewhere in my code a function with arity 3? What should be the type for the second template argument?

Comment: You'd let the second parameter be deduced. If you want type-erasure, use Jarod's answer.

Comment: @Caleth, it is not a deduced context (CTAD is all or nothing). you might still create `makeDiscreteFun`.

Comment: When I try to create a function like this `auto add = DiscreteFun<2>([](int x, int y) { return x+y; });` I get an error `wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)`

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka You can `auto f = [](int x, int y) { return x+y; }; auto add = DiscreteFun<2, decltype(f)>(f);`, or use `makeDiscreteFun`

Comment: this is beautiful!

Comment: Note sure I would use forwarding reference and possibly store reference in `DiscreteFun` though.

Comment: There seems to be another problem with this approach. If I create two `DiscreteFun` objects from lambdas they have different types and, therefore, I cannot combine them in one function, etc. Example: https://pastebin.com/HTiKAQLz

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Yes, that's exactly what I mean by "If you want type-erasure, use Jarod's answer."